# Microsoft Graph Content return null

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve the content of my word document stored in my company SharePoint.
The code is as follows:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
DriveItem document = await graphClient.Sites[_siteId].Drive.Items[remoteId].Request().GetAsync();
DocumentDTO dto = new DocumentDTO { Content = document.Content };
```

The dto has accessed the other information contained in the DriveItem such as Id and Name, but I don't understand why I can't access the content.

Looking for any possible help :-) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the example response in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#response-1), the content is not returned when you make call as you have done in your example.

To get the content you would need to make a different/separate request as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example).

Therefore, your code should look like something like this to get the content.

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
Stream content = await graphClient.Sites[_siteId].Drive.Items[remoteId].Content.Request().GetAsync();
DocumentDTO dto = new DocumentDTO { Content = content  };
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have this message now : Code: invalidRequest
Message: The provided item ID is not valid for the requested drive

Comment: I just tested this and the content returned is of type `MemoryStream` that I can read. Could you try out the request on the next comment replacing the itemId and remoteID params on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/_siteId/drive/items/remoteId

Answer (score 2):

I end up doing this to retrieve my content in Stream.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var document = await graphClient.Sites[_siteId].Drive.Items[remoteId].Request().GetAsync();
var url = document.AdditionalData["@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"].ToString();

HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```